# connect counter with items in an array react hooks

Tags: reactjs, github, react-hooks

I have a counter where I can decrement and increment the counter. I have also an array with items like so:

```
  const gitHubRepos = [
    'repo0',
    'repo1',
    'repo2',
    'repo3',
  ]
```

I need to use the counter as an index for the above array (`repo0` if the counter is 0, `repo1` if it's 1, ...) and fetch information about the GitHub repository from GitHub's API: `https://api.github.com/repos/{repoName}`. But how can I connect both the counter with the array and at the same time fetch information for a specific repo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use useEffect to fetch depending on your counter[. e.g.:](https://codesandbox.io/s/pedantic-feynman-dy9xho?file=/src/App.js)

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const [counter, setCounter] = useState(0)
  const gitHubRepos = [
    'repo0',
    'repo1',
    'repo2',
    'repo3',
  ]
  useEffect(()=>{
    console.log(`${gitHubRepos[counter]}`)
    fetch(`https://api.github.com/repos/${gitHubRepos[counter]}`);

  },[counter])
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
      <button onClick={()=>setCounter(counter+1)}>increment</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answer! It helped me a lot :)